# mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY not recognized

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver, on-duplicate-key

This statement randomly stopped working. I believe it is because of a new version of WAMP I am using 4.5.2 .

```
INSERT INTO at_user_listing_settings (userID, rfID, userID_rfID, Watching) VALUES(177, 35888, '177_35888', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Watching='1'
```

I get this error:

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 138)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "DUPLICATE" at position 141)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "KEY" at position 151)
```

I cant seem to find anything wrong with the syntax, was `ON DUPLICATE KEY` changed or deprecated?

Comment: You are using `4.5.2` **of what**?

Comment: Do you get this error **on this exact query**??

Comment: show as the output of : SELECT version();

Comment: Are you sure you are using MYSQL?

Comment: Is this part of some PHP code, if so **show the PHP code**

Comment: I am using WAMP, mySql v: 5.7.9, php: 5.6.16, phpMyAdmin: Version information: 4.5.2, latest stable version: 4.6.1

Comment: So you are using WAMPServer 3 Is this part of some PHP code?

Comment: The sql statement is produced in PHP, but I am attempting to insert the sql statement directly into phpmyAdmin to see if it works, so the PHP can be eliminated from this problem right now. 
Not sure if this is wampServer 3.

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured this thing out.

When you download a new version of WAMP, it sets the mysql to "Strict" mode by default. My real server hosted by hostgator must have more lenient restrictions. When trying to run the code locally, the code was correct, but the sql statements were running into problems when trying to update or insert into the database (also local).

For example, Strict mode required columns with boolean values to have a default value. If any column did not have a default value it would fail when trying to insert. The worst part is it wont return an apache or php error, so it made it extremely difficult to debug. It also did not like "ON DUPLICATE KEY".

To solve this problem I went into the WAMP > MySQL > my.ini > and looked for `sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"`.

I then removed `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, and everything started working like it was supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be a `phpMyAdmin` issue!

See [github errors that have been reported](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11628)

It seems rather old, but I see no reference to a fix, and it is still OPEN

We provided an ADDON for a similiar tool called [Adminer, SourceForge download link here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Applications/wampserver3_x86_adminer4.2.4.exe/download) as people were having a few odd issues with phpMyAdmin

Download that and it will install straight into WAMPServer and appear on the WAMPServer homepage in the "Your Aliases" menu

Comment: I give you +1 for at least knowing that it was a phpmyadmin issue and not a code issue. Although technically it was a mysql setting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rewrite your query to this:

```
INSERT INTO at_user_listing_settings
SET
  userID = 177,
  rfID = 35888,
  userID_rfID = '177_35888',
  Watching = '1'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Watching = '1'
```

Comment: I tried the above statement but still get similar error, it is also saying something about another column. 'Notes' perhaps that is causing the issue?

Error: Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 151)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "DUPLICATE" at position 154)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "KEY" at position 164)
An alias was previously found. (near "'1'" at position 189)

#1364 - Field 'Notes' doesn't have a default value

Im wondering if the last error part could have something to do with it...